# Adding aliases inboxes using Postfix

Tags: users, email, postfix

I set up Postfix to run locally and receive emails to myusername@localhost.

How do I add other addresses (e.g. test1@localhost, test@localhost etc) which would work as aliases for myusername@localhost so that when an email comes to one of these addresses, it gets into the myusername@localhost inbox?

I read quite a lot of postfix documentation but it is confusing because I am not sure what I should use: aliases, virtual domains, virtual users or else.

Answer (score 1):

Locally, use the /etc/aliases file (which is self documented on popular distributions).

Then run

```
newaliases
```